# Xamarin - setting a collection to custom bindable property in XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom `ContentView` with a defined bindable property:

```
    public IEnumerable<SomeItem> Items
    {
        get => (IEnumerable<SomeItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        set => SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Items),
        typeof(IEnumerable<SomeItem>),
        typeof(MyControl),
        propertyChanged: (bObj, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
        }
    );
```

How can I set a value to this in XAML?

I tried:

```
<c:MyControl>
   <c:MyControl.Items>
      <x:Array Type="{x:Type c:SomeItem}">
           <c:SomeItem />
           <c:SomeItem />
           <c:SomeItem />
      </x:Array>
   </c:MyControl.Items>
</c:MyControl>
```

But getting from time to time following compilation error:

```
error : Value cannot be null.
error : Parameter name: fieldType
```

I'm doing something wrong? Is there a different way?

Comment: I tested your code - it works fine! I think this compilation error is a false positive from intellisense. Also, would recommend that you change the `returnType` argument (in Binding.Create)  to `IEnumerable<SomeItem>` from `IEnumerable<CarouselTabbedItem>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ContentView to something like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : ContentView
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SomeItem>();

    public MyControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Items),
        typeof(ObservableCollection<SomeItem>),
        typeof(MyControl)
    );

    void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //Here do what you need to do when the collection change
    }
}
```

Your IEnumerable property change it for an ObservableCollection and subscribe for the `CollectionChanged` event.

Also do some changes in the BindableProperty.

So now in your XAML you can add the items like this:

```
<c:MyControl>
   <c:MyControl.Items>
        <c:SomeItem />
        <c:SomeItem />
        <c:SomeItem />
        <c:SomeItem />
    </c:MyControl.Items> 
</c:MyControl>
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: It seems not worked. I add some item to the `Items` but `Items_CollectionChanged` is not  triggered.

Comment: Not the best, Items_CollectionChanged event subscribing must not be in the constructor. Instead of this, use PropertyChanged, PropertyChanging on BindableProperty.