# Add values to custom collection property in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to add values to a custom collection property via XAML:

```
<local:OnePageHeaderView>
  <local:OnePageHeaderView.RightIconViewCollection>
    <toolkit:IconView Source="one.png"></toolkit:IconView>
    <toolkit:IconView Source="two.png"></toolkit:IconView>
    <toolkit:IconView Source="three.png"></toolkit:IconView>
  </local:OnePageHeaderView.RightIconViewCollection>
</local:OnePageHeaderView>
```

I did set up the custom property and the `PropertyChanged` Event like this:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty RightIconViewCollectionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "RightIconViewCollection",
    returnType: typeof(ObservableCollection<IconView>),
    declaringType: typeof(OnePageHeaderView),
    defaultValue: new ObservableCollection<IconView>(),
    propertyChanged: RightIconViewCollectionPropertyChanged);

public ObservableCollection<IconView> RightIconViewCollection
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<IconView>)GetValue(RightIconViewCollectionProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(RightIconViewCollectionProperty, value);
    }
}

private static void RightIconViewCollectionPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (OnePageHeaderView)bindable;
    control.RightIconViewCollection = (ObservableCollection<IconView>)newValue;
}
```

The problem is that `RightIconViewCollection` is always what I set as it's default value, no matter how many values I'm trying to add in my XAML.

I can confirm that `IconView` works as intended because I made some test cases by manually adding IconViews in the code behind and it worked.

Why is it that `RightIconViewCollection`'s value is always defaultValue (`new ObversableCollection()`) instead of the values I explicitly add in my XAML?

**EDIT:** Test case

**XAML:**

```
<local:OnePageHeaderView
  LeftIconViewSource="one.png">
  <local:OnePageHeaderView.RightIconViewCollection>
    <toolkit:IconView Source="two.png"></toolkit:IconView>
    <toolkit:IconView Source="three.png"></toolkit:IconView>
  </local:OnePageHeaderView.RightIconViewCollection>
</local:OnePageHeaderView>
```

**OnePageHeaderView:**

```
public OnePageHeaderView()
{
    Init();
}

private void Init()
{
    IconView leftIconView = new IconView
    {
        Source = LeftIconViewSource // LeftIconViewSource has value "one.png" which was assigned in XAML
    };

    ObservableCollection<IconView> iconViewCollection = new ObservableCollection<IconView>(RightIconViewCollection); // RightIconViewCollection has default value instead of assigned value in XAML
}
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, can you rephrase this into a question? Are you looking to work out how to detect when items have been added?

Comment: @JamesCroft edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for collection-type bindable properties should *not* be set using the `BindableProperty.Create` method but in the constuctor of the class.

It's the same as for WPF dependency properties which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/collection-type-dependency-properties).

You'll find a working example of how to implement a collection-type bindable property here:

[Xamarin - setting a collection to custom bindable property in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724440/xamarin-setting-a-collection-to-custom-bindable-property-in-xaml)

Comment: I need `RightIconViewCollection` with the added values in the constructor already because I'm trying to populate the items in the constructor. Works if I have custom properties which are not collections, but collections never hold the values I added in XAML when I reach the constructor of `OnePageHeaderView`. I seem to be overlooking something... At which point can I populate the items if I set the default value in the constructor as suggested by the docs?

Comment: In the constructor. How are the values that you define in the XAML supposed to be added *before* the constructor of the class has returned? This is not possible. There needs to be an instance created before the XAML parser can add any values to it.

Comment: I've added a test case which shows how another custom property gets it's value assigned from XAML while the custom collection property doesn't. Please see my edit.

Comment: Again, you can't expect the collection to have any values that you define in XAML in the constructor. This makes no sense as I explained in my previous comment. Any default values should be defined in the class definition. In the XAML markup, you create an instance of the class. You don't define any default values in there.